# SQL Server : slow query with 3 "OR" condition and order by Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, select, sql-order-by

My query:

```
SELECT TOP 30 a.*  
FROM Car 
WHERE (ModelId = 642 AND RegionId IN (23, 63, 1, 30, 5, 6, 7, 9, 15)) OR
      (ModelId = 242 AND RegionId IN (23, 63, 1, 30, 5, 6, 7, 9, 15, 26)) OR 
      (ModelId = 334 AND RegionId IN (23, 63, 1, 30, 5, 6, 7, 9, 15, 26)) 
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

It executes in 30 seconds.

If I remove `order by Id` section, it executes in 1 second.

Or if I remove one `OR` condition, it also executes in 1 second.

```
WHERE (ModelId = 642 AND RegionId IN (23, 63, 1, 30, 5, 6, 7, 9, 15)) OR    
      (ModelId = 242 AND RegionId IN (23, 63, 1, 30, 5, 6, 7, 9, 15, 26)) 
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Columns `ModelId` and `RegionId` has indexes. `Id` is primary key.

Execution plan show that 97% clustered index searched for Id.

Please, help me. Why so slowly for 3 `OR` condition with `ORDER BY`?

Comment: consider replacing or with union - also whenever u order by its gonna slow the query down

Comment: I understood. I added an option OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 8649) for parallelism and the query was executed in 1 second. strange that the mssql did not guess himself

Comment: So replacing with union sped it up for you?

Comment: Daniel Marcus, yes. With 2 or condition mssql execute it with parallelism, but with 3 or without it. All is decided

Comment: very interesting - thanks for sharing that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to expand [`OR`](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/optimizer-transformations:-or-expansion)(from Oracle but idea is the same):

> OR expansion is a transformation that can be used to optimize disjunctive queries (queries that contain OR clauses).
>
> The basic idea in OR expansion is to transform a query containing disjunctions into the form of a UNION ALL query of two or more branches. This is done by splitting the disjunction into its components and associating each component with a branch of a UNION ALL query.

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM Car
   WHERE ModelId = 642 AND RegionId IN (23,63,1,30,5,6,7,9,15)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * 
   FROM Car
   WHERE ModelId = 242 AND RegionId IN (23,63,1,30,5,6,7,9,15,26)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *
   FROM car
   WHERE ModelId = 334 AND RegionId IN (23,63,1,30,5,6,7,9,15,26)
)
SELECT TOP 30 *
FROM cte
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: Might as well make it UNION ALL so it doesn't have to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worse

```
SELECT TOP 30 a.*  
FROM Car 
WHERE (ModelId in (642, 242, 334) AND RegionId IN (23, 63, 1, 30, 5, 6, 7, 9, 15)) 
   OR (ModelId in (242, 334) AND RegionId  = 26)
ORDER BY Id DESC
```