# Odd Performance benefit of adding union in large table query

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I have this table with around 5 million rows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Zip](
    [Coun_Code] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Zip] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Zip_Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Zip_Pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Zip] ASC,
    [Coun_Code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Can someone please help me understand why the second query only takes two secs, while the first takes around 9? I found out by copy-paste mistake...**

Q1: Without Union

```
DECLARE 
    @Filter nvarchar(50),
    @StartIndex int,
    @EndIndex int,
    @OnlyStartsWith bit

SELECT @Filter = 'c1210',
@StartIndex = 0,
@EndIndex = 100,
@OnlyStartsWith = 0

    IF @OnlyStartsWith = 1
        SET @Filter = @Filter + '%';
    ELSE
        SET @Filter = '%' + @Filter + '%';

    DECLARE @ZipFilter varchar(10) = @Filter;

    WITH NumberedZips AS
    (
         SELECT Zip, Zip_Name, Coun_Code, [State], Active, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ZIP) as rowNum
         FROM 
            (
            SELECT Zip, Zip_Name, Coun_Code, [State], Active 
            FROM Zip z
            WHERE
                z.Zip LIKE @ZipFilter OR z.Zip_Name LIKE @Filter
            --UNION
            --SELECT Zip, Zip_Name, Coun_Code, [State], Active
            --FROM Zip z
            --WHERE
            --  z.Zip LIKE @ZipFilter OR z.Zip_Name LIKE @Filter
        ) filteredZips      
    )
    SELECT 
        COUN_CODE,
        ZIP_NAME,
        ZIP,
        Active,
        [State]
    FROM NumberedZips nz
    WHERE 
        rowNum BETWEEN @StartIndex AND @EndIndex
```

[image: Q1 Execution plan]

Q2: With Union

```
DECLARE 
    @Filter nvarchar(50),
    @StartIndex int,
    @EndIndex int,
    @OnlyStartsWith bit

SELECT @Filter = 'c1210',
@StartIndex = 0,
@EndIndex = 100,
@OnlyStartsWith = 0

    IF @OnlyStartsWith = 1
        SET @Filter = @Filter + '%';
    ELSE
        SET @Filter = '%' + @Filter + '%';

    DECLARE @ZipFilter varchar(10) = @Filter;

    WITH NumberedZips AS
    (
         SELECT Zip, Zip_Name, Coun_Code, [State], Active, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ZIP) as rowNum
         FROM 
            (
            SELECT Zip, Zip_Name, Coun_Code, [State], Active 
            FROM Zip z
            WHERE
                z.Zip LIKE @ZipFilter OR z.Zip_Name LIKE @Filter
            UNION
            SELECT Zip, Zip_Name, Coun_Code, [State], Active
            FROM Zip z
            WHERE
                z.Zip LIKE @ZipFilter OR z.Zip_Name LIKE @Filter
        ) filteredZips      
    )
    SELECT 
        COUN_CODE,
        ZIP_NAME,
        ZIP,
        Active,
        [State]
    FROM NumberedZips nz
    WHERE 
        rowNum BETWEEN @StartIndex AND @EndIndex
```

[image: Q2 Execution plan]

As far as I can see they are using the same index. It does not help/work to remove either filter on the nested SELECT statements, then it also takes around 9 secs. I also tried adding an index on Zip_Name, but that didn't make a difference either.

Comment: Is this result reproducible?  Could it be a one-time quirk due to server load?

Comment: **[OR expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758299/5070879)** quite common scenario, parallelism did the job. But you need to know that  `col LIKE '%sth%'` is [notSARGable](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/) so you will end up with index/table scan instead of seek.

Comment: Can't try it at the moment but if you put an order by in the cte on your clustered index  I'm going to wager you will see similar performance in the first example

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: I could reproduce this over and over, so not a one timer

Comment: Just tried again now with more users on the system - now it was still 1-2 sec for Q2, but 11-12 sec for Q1.

Answer (score 0):

I have not explanation for why the second would be faster. 
Try this:

```
WITH NumberedZips AS
(
     SELECT Zip, Zip_Name, Coun_Code, [State], Active
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ZIP) as rowNum
     FROM 
     (  SELECT Zip, Zip_Name, Coun_Code, [State], Active 
          FROM Zip z
         WHERE z.Zip LIKE @ZipFilter
        UNION
        SELECT Zip, Zip_Name, Coun_Code, [State], Active
          FROM Zip z
         WHERE z.Zip_Name LIKE @Filter
    ) filteredZips      
)
SELECT COUN_CODE, ZIP_NAME, ZIP, Active, [State]
  FROM NumberedZips nz
 WHERE rowNum BETWEEN @StartIndex AND @EndIndex
```

Comment: This is actually what I mention at the end of the post that I tried, but oddly enough, this is still slow. Any other clues are appreciated